# Renaming data in a Seurat object metadata

Tags: r, rename, seurat

I have a seurat object "gunion.data".
The metadata for gunion.data@meta.data$orig.ident is either "control, "ischemia", "synIRI" or "alloIRI". I would like to change ""synIRI" and "alloIRI" into "other".

I tried this
 `gunion.data@meta.data$orig.ident["alloIRI"] <- "other"`

but it gave me an error:
Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, orig.ident, value = c("control", "control", : replacement has 26933 rows, data has 26932

How should I format the code to change all "alloIRI" and "synIRI" in the data into "other"?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is rename an Ident.
The below should work once you've changed your idents to 'orig.ident'.

```
Idents(gunion.data) <- 'orig.ident'
gunion.data <- RenameIdents(object = gunion.data, `synIRI` = "other", `alloIRI` = "other")

Idents(gunion.data) #to confirm the change has happened.
```

I would suggest you also have a look at the Seurat Essential commands, found [here](https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/essential_commands.html).

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you. Unfortunately I dont appear to have enough reputation to upvote so I just comment. I'm new here :)

Comment: glad it worked out for you :) 
No prob, when you get it, it would be great for you to hit the top arrow key next to my answer so mark it as answered. All the best.